# SwiftUI Observable object doesn't update UI on first attempt

Tags: swiftui, observableobject

## Issue

The `@ObservableObject` ViewModel only updates the UI after closing and re-opening the view. Once this update has happened, every subsequent change in the `@Published` var inside the `@ObservableObject` triggers an automatic update.

## Context

I have a model called 'Stack' in my project.

```
struct Stack: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var isPinned = false
}
```

I have a view (NavigationMenuView) which presents all of the stacks in a scroll view
import SwiftUI

```
struct NavigationMenuView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = NavigationMenuViewModel()

    @EnvironmentObject var environmentObjects: EnvironmentObjects

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            NavigationView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    ScrollView {
                        ForEach(viewModel.stacks){ stack in
                            StackRow(
                                stack: stack,
                                lftButtonAction: {
                                    self.viewModel.toggleIsPinned(for: stack)
                                },
                                rhtButtonAction: {
                                    self.viewModel.deleteStack(stack: stack)
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }

                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"))
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: addNewStackButton)
                .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray6).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
            }.zIndex(1)

            if environmentObjects.newStackViewIsShown {

                VStack{
                    Spacer()
                    NewStackView(viewModel: NewStackViewModel())
                }
                .onDisappear{
                    self.viewModel.fetchStacks()
                }
                .zIndex(2)
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            self.viewModel.fetchStacks()
        }
    }
}
```

The view model for this view has a `@Published var stacks = [Stack]()` array which gets updates by `fetchStacks()`.

The NavigationMenuView has a subview (NewStackView) which creates a new 'stack' (using the ViewModel) using this button:

```
            Button(action: {
                if !self.isAddButtonDisabled{
                    self.viewModel.addNewStack(title: self.title)
                    self.environmentObjects.newStackViewIsShown = false
                }
            }) {
                Text("Add")
                    .padding(.vertical, 16.0)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                        .foregroundColor(addButtonColor)
                    )
            }
            .disabled(isAddButtonDisabled)
```

## My own progress

I have found out that this only occurs when the `NewStackView` is presented as a subview of the NavigationMenuView. When presenting it as a modal view using `.sheet()` the NewStackView updates straight away.